# Best/Fastest way to read 3k of sheets from an Excel and Upload them in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an Excel file with 3k worth of sheets. I've currently reading the sheets one by one, converting to a dataframe, append to a list and repeat. 
An iteration in the for loop lasts aprox 90 seconds, which is a huge amount of time. Each sheet has around 35 rows of data with 5 columns.

Can somebody suggest a better methodology in approaching this?

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import time

nr_pages_workbook = list(range(1,3839))
nr_pages_workbook = ['Page '+str(x) for x in nr_pages_workbook]
list_df = []

start = time.time()
for number in nr_pages_workbook:

    data = pd.read_excel('D:\\DEV\\Stage\\Project\\Extras.xlsx',sheet_name=number)
    list_df.append(data)
    break

stop = time.time() - start

Df_Date_Raw = pd.concat(list_df)
```

Comment: That seems reasonable, I bet most of the time would be due to read the excel files. And you only need to do it once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try passing `nr_pages_workbook` directly to `sheet_name` param in `read_excel`, according to the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) it can be a list, and the return value will be a dict of dataframes. This way you can avoid the overhead of opening and reading the file in every cycle.

Or just simply omit the parameter, and read all sheets into a dict, and then concatenate from the dict:

```py
data = pd.read_excel('D:\\DEV\\Stage\\Project\\Extras.xlsx')
df = pd.concat([v for k,v in data.items()])
```

Answer (score 2):

You are reading the whole file again whenever you are iterating through the loop. I would suggest reading it once using ExcelFile and then just accessing a particular sheet in the loop. Try:

```
import pandas as pd
xl = pd.ExcelFile('foo.xls')
sheet_list = xl.sheet_names
for i in sheet_list:
    if i ==0:
        df = xl.parse(i)
    else:
        df = df.append(xl.parse(i), ignore_index=True)
```